# Does a Sengir Vampire survive when blocked by four 1/1s?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

1. I attack with [Sengir Vampire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=368525) which is a 4/4
2. My opponent declares four 1/1 blockers

Would Sengir Vampire die or would it gain counters from the three 1/1 creatures that died before attacking the last 1/1 blocker? Thus allowing it to survive while killing the four 1/1 blockers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of the creatures will deal their respective damage at the same time. Since [Sengir Vampire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=368525)'s +1/+1 ability is a triggered ability, it uses the stack, and before any of the +1/+1 counters go onto the Vampire, it will die.

State-based actions (like death from damage) will happen before the triggered ability on the stack can resolve.

If any of the creatures involved have first strike, however, this changes things:

- If the Sengir Vamire has first strike, it will deal it's damage before the blockers, killing them before they have a chance to deal damage, giving it the +1/+1 counters
- If the blockers have first strike, they deal damage to the vampire before it deals damage to them, killing the vampire while they remain alive
- If all parties have first strike, the outcome is the same as if none of them did.